# Windows service and passing in a password

Tags: windows-services

My windows service needs a password to access an external resource. At present I'm putting the password in the App.config file, on installing the service I encrypt it and copy it to the user configuration file in code and then edit it out of the App.config.

This is a bit long winded and prone to error, it's easy to forget the last step and when I hand this code over I worry this will happen. Is there a better way to get this kind of information into a windows service?

Comment: run your service as a domain account, and grant that domain account access to the remote resource. if its file or SQLServer, its easy to do integrated authentication, and if not, there is likely a mechanism to use windows integrated auth in conjunction with the service.

Comment: Unfortunately using Windows integrated authentication  isn't an option.